# Zend DB Table: All Values are Strings

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am using Zend DB Table and DB Table Row.  When I get a row object for any of my tables, I see that the types have all been changed to strings, even the auto-incrementing primary key.

Is that normal? Do I need to explicitly define the schema to get around this?  (I thought I'd read all the Zend DB documentation.  Can't recall anything about this though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Zend_Db uses PDO for most connections, you're always going to get strings back from a `SELECT` query.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I had no idea!  So, as a general rule, how would you go about using the array elements?  Would you cast them in your client code whenever you used them?  Or would you put getters in the DB Table or Row classes to do the conversion for you?  I have read up on the DB mapper suggested by ArtWorkAD, and I don't think my system needs it in this case.